# How to auto recognize date format

Tags: node.js, date, momentjs

When I'm parsing xls data, I'm facing with a lot of different dates like `date`, `datetime`, or only `time`.

Example time: [image]

Example date without time: [image]

In document the first value is just a time, second just a date.

How can I figure out this case and recognize where is the date, where the time and where the DateTime?

Comment: do you actually need to output the format, or do you need to be able to parse this as datetime data?

Comment: I need to know the exact format because on the output I must have 08:45 or 17-10-2021 or 2020-12-10 10:20:22

Comment: your example "without time" has time in it :P

Comment: and that is a root of problem if you understand, because when you parsing xls it's not return date as is in xls format

Comment: like I said before, this cannot be done. You have to be able to list all possible date/time/datetime formats that you want to support. You cannot just support them all. There are hundreds of them and many of them could be interpreted in many different ways. "1:2:2020" could be either a date or time. "1/2" could be either 1st of Februrary or 2nd of January depending on where you come from. You have to be able to list what you're supporting and what you want to interpret it as. Then we can write some real code

Answer (score 0):

so it's either date, time or datetime. One easy way would be to write 3 regular expressions to determine which one you're dealing with. Something like

```js
function getType(dateStr) {
  if (/^\w{3} \w{3} \d{1,2} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} GMT\+\d+$/.test(dateStr)) { // matches 'Sat Mar 30 1899 05:24:10 GMT+030'
    return 'datetime';
  }
  if (otherRegExMatchingOnlyTime.test(dateStr)) {
    return 'time';
  }
  if (otherRegExMatchingOnlyDate.test(dateStr) {
    return 'date';
  }

  throw new Error(`Unsupported date format of ${dateStr}`);
}
```

I'm not writing all regular expressions here, since I don't have any proper examples of your date-only or time-only values

Comment: Problem here is that `Sat Mar 30 1899 05:24:10 GMT+030` is a time (06:22:10) and not datetime

Comment: please, post all possible inputs from the xls file and I'll extend my exmaple

Comment: I can't post all possible inputs, just imagine how many xls documents exist and store dates or just times with different format...

Comment: One example - `1899-12-30T05:24:07+02:02` is a `06:22:07` in document

Comment: if you want to support all possible formats in existence, then this is physically not doable. Starting with a simple problem of American vs rest of the world date format, where you don't know which number is the day and which is the month is (like is 1/2/2021 "first of february" or "January the second"?). You can list all formats that you want to support and write the regular expressions for them. I don't think another way exists